# Asynchronous object sharing in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I have a very basic understanding about spark and I am trying to find something that can help me achieve the following :

Have a Pool of objects shared over all the nodes, asynchronously.

What I am thinking of currently, is, lets say there are ten nodes numbered from 1 to 10.
If I have a single object, I will have to make my object synchronous in order for it to be accessible by any node. I do not want that.
Second option is, I can have a pool of say 10 objects.
I want to write my code in such a way that the node number 1 always uses the object number 1, the node number 2 always uses the object number 2 and so on..

A sample approach would be, before performing a task, get the thread ID and use the object number (threadID % 10). This would result in a lot of collisions and would not work.

Is there a way that I can somehow get a nodeID or processID, and make my code fetch an object according to that ID ? Or some other way to have an asynchronous pool of objects on my cluster?

I apologize if it sounds trivial, I am just getting started and cannot find a lot of resources pertaining to my doubt online.

PS : I am using a SparkStreaming + Kafka + YARN setup if it matters.

Comment: Spark has no global shared memory, so shared objects are not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

Spark automatically partitions the data across all available cluster nodes; you don't need to control or keep track of where the partitions are actually stored. Some RDD operations also require shuffling which is fully managed by Spark, so you can't rely on the layout of the partitions.

Sharing an object only makes sense if it's immutable. Each worker node receives a copy of the original object, and any local changes to it will not be reflected on other nodes. If that's what you need, you can use `sc.broadcast()` to efficiently distribute an object across all workers prior to a parallel operation.